# c# application which detects form fields in a browser

Tags: c#, html, browser

I created a winForm application which fills the fields of a web site :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.site.com”));
            this.textBox1.Text = this.webBrowser1.Version.ToString();
        }
private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document =
       this.webBrowser1.Document;

            document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("Value","user");

        }
```

It works perfectly when the web site page is loaded in application control but when I want to open it in a new browser using `webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.site.com”),true);` the page fields are undetectable.
Is there a solution for this problem?  Thanks in advance

Comment: You might have to wait for the document to load: see the docs for [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your response I used this method : 
`
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("complete");
        }
`
but unless the page is loaded in the form, the message box is not shown. I think there it's not possible interaction between an application and external browser content

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that the page opens in a browser, and you're right that it is not possible to access the document from code.